# Transferring data to/from a callback from/to a worker thread

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, callback, pthreads

My current application is a toy web service written in C designed to replicate the behaviour of http://sprunge.us/ (takes data in via http POST, stores it to disk, returns the client a url to the data - also serves data that has been previously stored upon request).

The application is structured such that a thread pool is instantiated with worker threads (just a function pointer that takes a void* parameter) and a socket is opened to listen to incoming connections. The main loop of the program comprises a `sock = accept(...)` call and then a `pool_add_task(worker_function_parse_http, sock)` to enable requests to be handled quickly.
The `parse_http` worker parses the incoming request and either adds another task to the work queue for storing the data (POST) or serving previously stored data (GET).

My problem with this approach stems from the use of the [`http-parser`](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser) library which uses a callback design to return parsed data (all http parsers that I looked at used this style). The problem I encounter is as such:

My `parse_http` worker:

1. Buffers data from the accepted socket (the function's only parameter, at this stage)
2. Sets up a `http-parser` object as per its API, complete with setting callback functions for it to call when it finishes parsing the URL or BODY or whatever. (These functions are of a fixed type signature defined by the `http-parser` lib, with a pointer to a buffer containing the parsed data relevant to the call, so I can't pass in my own variables and solve the problem that way. These functions also return a status code to the http parser, so I can't use the return values either. The suggested way to get data out of the parser for later use is to copy it out to a global variable during the callback - fun with multiple threads.)
3. Execute the parser on the buffered socket data. At this stage, the parser is expected to call its set up callbacks when it parses different sections of the buffer. The callback is supplied with parsed data relevant to each callback (e.g. BODY segment supplied to body_parsed callback function).
4. Well, this is where the problem shows. The parser has executed, but I don't have any access to the parsed data. Here is where I would add a new task to the queue with a worker function to store the received body data or another to handle the GET request for previously stored data. These functions would need to be supplied with both the parsed information (POST data or GET url) as well as the accepted socket so that the now delegated work can respond to the request and close the connection.

Of course, the obvious solution to the problem is simply to not use this thread-pool model with asynchronous practices, but I would like to know, for now and for later, how best to tackle this problem.

How can I get the parsed data from these callbacks back to the worker thread function. I've considered simply making my `on_url_parsed` and `on_body_parsed` do the rest of the application's job (storing and retrieving data), but of course I no longer have the client's socket to respond back to in these contexts.

If needed, I can post up the source code to the project when I get the chance.

Edit: It turns out that it is possible to access a user defined `void *` from within the callbacks of this particular http-parser library as the callbacks are passed a reference to the caller (the parser object) which has a user-definable data field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well-designed callback interface would provide for you to give the parser a `void *` which it would pass on to each of the callback functions when it calls them.  The callback functions you provide know what type of object it points to (since you provide both the data pointer and the function pointers), so they can cast and properly dereference it.  Among other advantages, this way you can provide for the callbacks to access a local variable of the function that initiates the parse, instead of having to rely on global variables.

If the parser library you are using does not have such a feature (and you don't want to switch to a better-designed one), then you can probably use thread-local storage instead of global variables.  How exactly you would do that depends on your thread library and compiler, or you could roll your own by using thread identifiers as keys to thread-specific slots in some global data structure (a hash table for instance).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I figured this would be a likely solution but I wasn't sure if I was overcomplicating things trying to get threads/async stuff to play nice together, so it's good to hear it from someone else.

I did find a solution in a feature that wasn't quite documented in this specific parser's API, so that's what I'll try first.